# Hibernate doesn't add records to association

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a m:n relation beetwen objects (Meeting, Person) as many persons can be participant of many meetings.

I've set it like this

Meeting

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "meetings")
protected Set<Person> participants = new HashSet<Person>();
```

Person

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "person_meeting",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "meeting_id")}
)
protected Set<Meeting> meetings = new HashSet<Meeting>();
```

Id DB hibernate created me table meeting_participants with two fields: meeting_id, person_id. Cool, just as I wanted. 
Now problematic case. I've create Meeting object and I saved it to DB. Than I create set of users, I add it to meeting

```
this.saveMeeting.setParticipants(set);
```

Hibernate displays:

```
Hibernate: update Meeting set duration=?, meetingDate=?, room=? where meeting_id=?
```

Nothing added to association. What do I need to change ?

// EDIT
I've changed in Meeting definition of the field

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "meetings", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
protected Set<Person> participants = new HashSet<Person>();
```

Now I get error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
```

It is in this method

```
public static Long add(Meeting meeting) {
    SessionFactory sf = null;
    Session session = null;

    sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    session = sf.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        session.save(meeting);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
    } catch(HibernateException e){
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Long(-1);
    }
    session.close();

    return meeting.getId();
}
```

The line that is causing the problem is:

**session.save(meeting);**

**EDIT**

Ok I've closed session properly. Everything works find BUT only when I'm creating new objects. When I want to update association it doesn not work. So the question is. How to update association ??

Answer (score 2):

This question is asked every two days. You just initialized one side of the association, and you chose the one that Hibernate ignores. A bidirectional association has an *owner* side, and an *inverse* side. Hibernate only considers the *owner* side. And the *owner* side is the one which *doesn't* have the `mappedBy` attribute.

So you need to initialize the other side of the association:

```
for (Participant p : set) {
    p.getMeetings().add(saveMeeting);
}
```

Comment: that didn`t help. Nothing changed. This is debug from hibernate: Hibernate: select meetings0_.person_id as person1_0_1_, meetings0_.meeting_id as meeting2_1_, meeting1_.meeting_id as meeting1_3_0_, meeting1_.duration as duration3_0_, meeting1_.meetingDate as meetingD3_3_0_, meeting1_.room as room3_0_ from person_meeting meetings0_ inner join Meeting meeting1_ on meetings0_.meeting_id=meeting1_.meeting_id where meetings0_.person_id=?
Hibernate: update Meeting set duration=?, meetingDate=?, room=? where meeting_id=?

Comment: I assumed the entities wre attached. If you want the persons to be persistent, you need to save them.

Comment: All Person objects are already in DB. They are picked from list so they are in life cycle and they exists with id etc

Comment: I`ve managed to achive my goal by manaul creating 2 person objects and 1 meeting. adding everything and saving it. But I need to do that with update

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. I didn't think about that so I didn not wrote it. Person was a top class and it was extended by two others. I've changed update action so that it took an instance of Object class. That way I'm able to update association